# Java Band Matrix implemeantion and lost on syntax

Tags: java, matrix

```
      C1    c2   c3    c4   

 R1   2     -1   0      0
 R2  -1      2  -1      0
 R3   0     -1   2     -1
 R4   0      0  -1      1
```

I want to create a band matrix like this. For this I search on internet and import Java Matrix ToolKit. Where there is a option to create brand matrix. The syntax of the band matrix is like public BandMatrix(int n, int kl, int ku)

Constructor for BandMatrix

Parameters:

n - Size of the matrix. Since the matrix must be square, this equals both the number of rows and columns
kl - Number of bands above the main diagonal (superdiagonals)
ku - Number of bands below the main diagonal (subdiagonals)

Now as there is no example or documentation about band matrix I cannot create or display the matrix. But still I am trying to write down a code block then lost.

```
import no.uib.cipr.matrix.BandMatrix;
public class T1 {
public static void main(String args[]){
            BandMatrix B=new BandMatrix(4,1,1);

}
```

}

Now what how could I introduce the number that is in the above matrix and how could I display it? If any one have any idea using band matrix please share it with me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
import no.uib.cipr.matrix.BandMatrix;

public class BandMatrixTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BandMatrix bandMatrix = new BandMatrix(5, 1, 1);
        initMatrix(bandMatrix, 5);
        printMatrix(bandMatrix, 5);
    }

    public static void initMatrix(BandMatrix matrix, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                try {
                    // generate and add a number between 10 and 20
                    matrix.add(i, j, 10 + (int) (Math.random() * ((20 - 10) + 1)));
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printMatrix(BandMatrix matrix, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4.0f", matrix.get(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```